# settings.gradle file not found error while renaming zbar-sample

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, file-rename, zbar

From https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner I've imported zbar and zbar-sample, when I try to rename **zbar-sample** it fails by saying `settings.gradle` not found. But I do have `settings.gradle` in root. It's content is:

`include "zbar", "zbar-sample"`

[image]

Comment: No @VivekMishra. `zbar-sample` ends at `zbar-sample.iml`